# Howto set reponsive inline UL list

Tags: html, css

I have one span inside him name of list, beside of span is ul list, I wan't to setlist full width, and resizable when content is 5 li, i set width for ul but not working, because, my last li move to a new row.

Here jsfiddle, resize windows preview and set to small, my ul is not ok.
I wan;t to create responsive using only html and css.
http://jsfiddle.net/n6vm1q1e/

HTML

```
<div class="row1 margintop2">
                <span>SPORT</span>
                    <div class="lista">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Football</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Basketball</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Tenis</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Other sports</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div><!--Closed div row1-->
```

CSS

```
.row1{
    width: 100%;
}
.row1 span{
    background-color: #ff0000;
    padding:10px 20px 10px 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    color:white;
    width: 14%;
}
.lista{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width:71%;
}
.row1 ul{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 13px;
}
.row1 ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    font-size: 0.7em;
    margin-left: 1px;
}
.row1 ul li a {
        color:#333;
}
.row1 ul li:before{
content:'|';
padding-right: 5px;
padding-left: -2px;
}
.row1 ul li:first-child:before{
    content:none !important;
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're asking. Are you saying you want the LI items to stay in one row until their are 5 LI items, and THEN turn to a vertical menu? Responsive designs are about the size of the window, not the number of LI elements you have. Can you explain a bit more what you are looking for?

Comment: Look, span with text SPORt, i want to set fixed width with padding:10px;, but li element to be other 100% width of free area, now i want to be span and ul with 5-6 element inline

Comment: Perhaps you could provide an image of what this is ***supposed*** to look like?

Comment: @Paulie_D
I want something like this on picture, and to be on smaller resolution to be the same
, can't width for span 15%, and for ul 85% i dont know why http://i.imgur.com/eZNHJ4I.png

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear but I think you want something like this:

```css
.row1 {
  width: 100%;
}
.row1 span {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  color: white;
  width: 14%;
}
.lista {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 71%;
}
.row1 ul {
  display: table;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.row1 ul li {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 0.7em;
  margin-left: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}
.row1 ul li a {
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.row1 ul li {
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
}
.row1 ul li:first-child {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row1 margintop2"> <span>SPORT</span>

  <div class="lista">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Football</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Basketball</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Tenis</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Other sports</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Closed div row1-->
```

Comment: That's it but not 100%useful, because if I add 3 <li> elements more my content deformed on small resolution, resize window and add more <li> elements and see, is ti posible to implement resizable?